# Handling variations in PGN (portable gaming notation) files

Tags: ios, xcode

I have made a parser for PGN file in objective c and have done all validation and representation of move on board but i have trouble regarding variation and recursive variations,i have parsed only simple PGN files.I have come across following issues
1.How to handle variation which data structure will be suitable?
2.How many recursive variation should be supported?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using a tree structure for the same. I have used linked list and the variation node link to make a variation branch.